# Destroy components when using navigateToSobject

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a fairly complex logic that is rendered by 3rd party lib.

When I navigate between components using navigateToComponent in LEX, it seems that they are not destroyed causing all sort of weird issues.

Part of my fight against component framework was already achieved by

```
  init: function(cmp, event, helper) {
    if( typeof MyLib !== 'undefined' && ! helper.isInitialiazed ){
      helper.isInitialiazed = true;
      helper.initEverything(cmp);
    }
  },
```

However if I flip between components, `helper.isInitialiazed` is always set to true afterwards.

**Edit**: link in the comments does indeed help to destroy component instances, but abstract components that these extend, and state in their helpers - do not get destroyed...

Comment: I've hit a similar problem and didn't get a good answer for it - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/200011/reliable-way-to-clear-a-setinterval-used-by-a-lightning-component.

Comment: Thanks, found locationChange trick few minutes earlier and it worked for me. Going to read this tho.

Comment: Its not working for me when I try to run my components in the console view though.

Comment: @KeithC oh no... and there is nothing about it Spring 18 console API's... Weird question tho - have you considered using setTimeout instead? I've read somewhere that setInterval might be not reliable as browsers tend to pause inactive tabs so you get weird effects with setInterval. Instead using chained setTimeout with timestamps is more reliable and in your case - perhaps it could self destroy?

Comment: You should not be putting state in to your helper, as it is shared across all instances of a component. There's likely a way to solve the problem, but this isn't it.

Comment: @sfdcfox without the doubt, but that was the choice by previous. Now I need to clean it up. There should be options for hard component reload.